# How in jQuery 3 get id of select inputs in .each function?

Tags: jquery, select

In my Laravel 5.7/ blade/ jQuery v3.3.1 / bootrap 4.1 I show select inputs based on `$groups` array, like

```
@foreach($groups as $nextGroup)
    <div class="form-row mb-3">
        <label class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 control-label pb-0 mb-0  mt-3" for="checked_user_access_{{ $nextGroup['id'] }}">
            {{ $nextGroup['name'] }}<br>
            <small>{{ $nextGroup['description'] }}</small>
        </label>
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            {{ Form::select('checked_user_access_'.$nextGroup['id'], $userGroupSelectedValueArray, !empty($nextGroup['is_checked']) ? 1 : 0, [ "id"=>'checked_user_access_'.$nextGroup['id'], "class"=>"form-control editable_field select_input update_user_access" ] ) }}
        </div>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

and I want in js function to get all selected data and to post them with ajax, like:

```
var update_user_access_selection = ''
$('select.update_user_access').each(function () {
    update_user_access_selection = update_user_access_selection + $(this).text() + ', ' + $(this).val() + ', ' + $(this).id + ',         '
...
```

as result in `update_user_access_selection` var I can get value selected/not selected, but I did not find if there is a way to get `id` of any 
select input to combine them and to post these data.

which is the valid way?

Thanks!

Comment: use `this.id` or `$(this).attr('id')` to retrieve it

Comment: `$(this).prop('id')`